# How to center link in td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I have problem with center links in td. The problem is that I don't know how many links there will be in this td. In some just only 1, but there can be also 14. They are placed horizontally ( but when there's too much then they are going to the next line - they have float:left added by me ). I can't center them. There is always space on the right, especially when width of one link is to wide and is going to another line. I tryed also do for my class .hour {display: inline-block } but then on small sizes all links are in one line and that looks bad. Is there a possibility to do that? I don't know or You understand me :D

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">{{$doctorsDeadlines['lekarz']['imie']}} {{$doctorsDeadlines['lekarz']['nazwisko']}}
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <hr class="visible-xs">
                <h4 class="text-center">Terminarz</h4>
                <br/>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                            <th class="text-center">{{$date}}</th>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                        <td class="hour-container">
                            <div class="hour-div">
                            @foreach($hours as $hour )
                                <a class="hour" href="#">{{$hour}}</a>
                            @endforeach
                            </div>

                        </td>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css code:

```
.hour {
color: white !important;
background-color: #6699CC;!important;
display: block;
padding: 5px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin: 3px;
font-size: 15px;
}

.hour:hover {
color: #000 !important;
background-color: #dee1ed;!important;
text-decoration: none;
}

.hour-div {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: yellow;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: you can't center a floating element, remove the float and give your td text-align: center

Comment: `text-align: center;` should be applied to the parent element of the text/inline elements you want to center. Not directly on the element you want centered. Also, floating your anchors will nullify text alignment, undo that.

Answer (score -1):

Try it or else comment;

Replace

```
               <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                        <th class="text-center">{{$date}}</th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                    <td class="hour-container">
                        <div class="hour-div">
                        @foreach($hours as $hour )
                            <a class="hour" href="../panel/wizyty/dodaj?id_lekarza={{$doctorsDeadlines['lekarz']['id']}}&data={{$date}}&godzina={{$hour}}">{{$hour}}</a>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </table>
```

with this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                            <th class="text-center">{{$date}}</th>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                        @foreach($hours as $hour )
                        <td class="hour-container">
                            <div class="hour-div">

                                <a class="hour" href="../panel/wizyty/dodaj?id_lekarza={{$doctorsDeadlines['lekarz']['id']}}&data={{$date}}&godzina={{$hour}}">{{$hour}}</a>

                            </div>

                        </td>
                        @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: But when I remove float, then each link is in one line on the 100% width of cell, one under one ( vertically ), but I want to my links be one by one ( horizontally ) , and when space is too less, then go to another line and again horizontally.

Comment: Edited the Answer

Comment: No no no, now it broke ;p

Comment: I tryed really a lot of solutions but I canno't to handle it

Comment: I edited main post, there's a site, where is exactly how I want to look like, but the hours are not centered.